# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the service (..). Please make sure that the argument repository at index[3] is available in the AuthModule context

Tags: postgresql, module, nestjs, repository

i recently tried nestjs for my project and I'm having a problem with my code like this.
What i have is 3 module, authModule, userModule, customerModule.
AuthModule handles authentication
UserModule handles basic user entity
CustomerModule handles additional user information

anwyays here my code

auth.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      Customer,
    ]),
    forwardRef(() => UserModule),
    forwardRef(() => CustomersModule),
    
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    CustomersService
  ],
  exports: [
    AuthService
  ],
})
```

user.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
    User,
    UserSettingsEntity,
    AuthenticationMethod,
    ExternalAuthenticationMethod,
    NativeAuthenticationMethod
    ]),
    //forwardRef(() => CustomersModule),
    //forwardRef(() => AuthModule)
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  exports: [UserService],
  providers: [UserService, ...handlers, ...helpers],
})
```

customer.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      Customer,
    ]),
    forwardRef(() => UserModule),
  ],
  controllers: [CustomersController],
  providers: [
    CustomersService,
    UserService,
  ],
  exports: [CustomersService],
})
```

customer.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Customer)
    private customerRepository: Repository<Customer>,
    private validatorService: ValidatorService,
    private commandBus: CommandBus,
    private userService: UserService,
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private userRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}
```

user.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private userRepository: Repository<User>,
    @InjectRepository(NativeAuthenticationMethod)
    private nativeAuthenticationMethodRepository: Repository<NativeAuthenticationMethod>,
    private passwordCipher: PasswordCipher,
    private validatorService: ValidatorService,
    private awsS3Service: AwsS3Service,
    private commandBus: CommandBus,
    private verificationTokenGenerator: VerificationTokenGenerator,
  ) {}
```

auth.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private jwtService: JwtService,
    private configService: ApiConfigService,
    private userService: UserService,
  ) {}
```

this is the error im getting, i dont know what i did wrong, i believe i did whats given on the documentation into my understanding

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CustomersService (CustomerRepository, ValidatorService, CommandBus, ?). Please make sure that the argument UserRepository at index [3] is available in the AuthModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is AuthModule a valid NestJS module?
- If UserRepository is a provider, is it part of the current AuthModule?
- If UserRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AuthModule?
```

I am expecting that my auth.service.ts will fix the dependency in my userService and customerService. while the userSevice also had a dependency with the customerService